# If ENUM allows for only certain data to be entered can it influence a second column?

Tags: mysql, enums, phpmyadmin

Using phpMyAdmin 5.6 to build a database installed using WAMP.

With ENUM you limit the possible entry into a field.

I have 2 columns that I want to interact with each other.

In column 1 you pick a state in column 2 you are presented with a list of counties only in the state you picked in column 1.

Can this even be done?

Or does this have to be done on the website development side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible to do through phpMyAdmin, and additionally I don't really see the point. Since you shouldn't be presenting phpMyAdmin to your users anyway, you should do this at the application layer when you're building the dialog for the user. Doing it only in phpMyAdmin doesn't seem to make much sense to me, and is not really using it for the intended purpose (which is database maintenance and administrative work, not end-user input). I'm